# how to hide hint and marker from displaying when items are dragged in devexpress wpf grid control

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

how to hide hint and marker from displaying when items are dragged in gridcontrol? Is there a property that can disable the behavior as it always not desirable to display hint and marker.

the marker and hint UI elements are described in the link below-

https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/11347/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Drag-and-Drop/End-User-Drag-and-Drop

Answer (score 0):

For Hint, set `DataViewBase.ShowDragDropHint` to false.
https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.DataViewBase.ShowDragDropHint.property

For Marker, I have not found any property to hide it, but creating an empty Template would work :
https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/119483/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Drag-and-Drop/Drop-Marker

```
    <dxg:TableView ShowDragDropHint="False">
        <dxg:TableView.DropMarkerTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid></Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </dxg:TableView.DropMarkerTemplate>
    </dxg:TableView>
```